# Flexible height of multiline UILabel with autolayout not working

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm creating a collectionview with a UILabel subviewed on it. The labels are supposed to be multiline (numberOfLines set to zero) and i use autolayout to determine its height.

Now the problem is that the label sometimes does not display one or two characters at the end and as you can see in the photo below the labels frame is closed and some of the characters are now shown.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Describe all the constraints on the label.

Comment: @Wain I added a screen shot of the interface builder.

Comment: @user1665325 Raasti haleh shomah? :)

Comment: have you set numberOfLines = 0?

Comment: @Arunakumari yes of course!

Comment: what are the values of Content Hugging Priority and Content Compression priority values

Comment: Why leading and centre constraints? Why not leading and trailing? And what is the preferred width set as?

Comment: @Arunakumari i dont even know how to set these values! can you help me out?

Comment: set those values to 1000 and try it again

Comment: @Wain it gives the same results. the preferred width is set to screen size minus 10.

Comment: @Arunakumari nothing! still some of the labels are not displaying their last character.

Comment: @milad sh you need to add outlet constraint of height and determine string height and then set height constraint of label according to outlet constraint.

Comment: remove the height constraint and add bottom constraint try with that

Comment: @user1665325 have you got solution?